# python type error: does not support indexing

Tags: python, typeerror

```
        import simplegui
        import random        
        top=52
        in_play=False
        suits=('C','S','H','D')
        ranks=('A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K')
        alist=range(0,52)

        def deal():
            global outcome,in_play,alist,top
            if not in_play:
                alist=range(0,52)
            in_play=True
            r = random.randint(0,top)
            card=Card(suits[alist[r]//13],ranks[alist[r]//4])  #line 73
            alist=alist.remove(alist[r])
            top=top-1
            return card
    class Card:
        def __init__(self,suit,rank):
            global suits,ranks
            if (suit in suits) and (rank in ranks):
                self.suit=suit
                self.rank=rank
            else:
                self.suite=None
                self.rank=None
                print "invalid card:",suit,rank

        def  __str__(self):
            return self.suit+self.rank
        def get_suit(self):
            return self.suit
        def get_rank(self):
            return self.rank
        def draw(self,canvas,pos):
            card_loc=(card_centre[0]+card_size[0]*ranks.index(self.rank),
                      card_centre[1]+card_size[1]*suits.index(self.suit) )
            canvas.draw_image(card_images,card_loc,card_size,[pos[0]+card_centre[0],pos[1]+card_centre[1]],card_size)
```

this a part of the code i ran in codeskulptor
its showing an error:
Line 73: TypeError: 'NoneType' does not support indexing
................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: your code isn't properly formatted. You might want to do that? Band indentation could change the meaning of python code completely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.remove` works inplace and returns `None`. Thus line 74 sets `alist` to `None`:

```
            alist=alist.remove(alist[r])
```

Just leave the assignment out.

Comment: i did that its now showing error: ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0, 0, 0)

Comment: That problem is not part of your question/code. You should ask a new one instead of commenting. If the answer helped you solve your issue, please accept it.

Comment: Alright sorry. Yes, leaving the assignment operator out solved the error

Answer (score 0):

import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(1)

def draw_triangle(1,c):
for side in range(3):
t.color(c)
t.forward(1)
t.right(360/3)

for single_triangle_color in ('blue', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'green'):
t.right(360/6)

draw_triangle(66,c)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).